# How do I overload LINQ IQueryable<TEntity> Where() to accept column name

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-sql

I would like to modify the following to accept the column name which will be searched in the Where method, something like:

```
        public TEntity GetEntity(int val)
        {
            TEntity entity = _DbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                   .Where(e => e.Id == val)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
            return entity;
        }
```

to be changed to

```
        public TEntity GetEntity(int val, string colName)
        {
            TEntity entity = _DbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                   .WhereWithColName(val, colName)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
            return entity;
        }
```

Expression trees still too complex for me...

Comment: Take a look at DynamicLinq:  https://dynamic-linq.net/

Comment: thanks.  should be possible without dynamic linq using expression trees.

Comment: Yes, of course, and this library uses expression trees to do this, but you expressed apprehension about writing the expression trees yourself (an admitedly laborious and complex technique).

Comment: My question to you is... *why?* what do you actually save or make better by adding this layer of indirection? Let's say your code goes from `context.Person.First(p => p.Name == "John)` to `mygetter.GetEntity<Person>("John", Person.Name)`. In what way is it actually *an improvement*?

Comment: @CaiusJard I think the target is ```mygetter.GetEntity<Person>("John", "Name")``` which makes it more generic.

Comment: @Martin that is exactly what I am aiming for, as I think I indicated clearly in my question.  This will be used in an Azure Function based web service.

Comment: @Martin ok, but my question remains unchanged

Comment: @CaiusJard, why is your question unchanged?   This will allow me to pass a column name in a webservice call.  Your imagined GetEntity is indeed useless but it is in no way what I am after or what I asked for in the question I posted.  Thank you for your valuable comments.

Comment: OK, so you want to pass it in a web service; how do you indicate TEntity?

Comment: using the route. Man, this isn't exactly helpful @CaiusJard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved it:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereById<TEntity, TKey>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, TKey value, string colName)
            where TEntity : class
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
    var propAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, colName);
    var valExpr = Expression.Constant(value);

    var predicate = Expression.Equal(propAccess,valExpr);

    var predicateLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(predicate, param);

    return query.Where(predicateLambda);
}
```

and the calling function is then:

```
public TEntity GetEntity(int val, string colName)
{
    TEntity entity = _DbContext.Set<TEntity>()
           .WhereById<TEntity, int>(val, colName)
           .FirstOrDefault();
    return entity;
}
```